# Options for Ethernet on Raspberry Pi Zero without USB

Tags: ethernet, pi-zero, remote

I'm working on a project involving a Raspberry Pi Zero (not W), and an Arduino Nano with sensors. I need to be able to read data off of the Raspberry Pi without using Wi-Fi, so I'm trying to put Ethernet on my Raspberry Pi. However, the only options I've seen either involve using a USB-Ethernet adapter/hub or using this [Arduino SPI-Ethernet ENC28J60 Board](http://raspi.tv/2015/ethernet-on-pi-zero-how-to-put-an-ethernet-port-on-your-pi).

Now, I would prefer to not use the USB-Ethernet adapter/hub, as I would like to have that exclusively for the Arduino and its sensors so that power from the USB port won't be split between the Arduino and Ethernet, but from what I've seen of the ENC28J60, it's not fast, and it shouldn't work due to requiring more current than the Pi's 3.3V GPIO pin can provide. I was wondering if there were any other options to have Ethernet on the Pi Zero that doesn't involve USB. Are there any official hats or modules that are commonly used (not depreciated, well documented, etc.)?

Comment: Have you seen this link? https://www.amazon.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet/s?k=raspberry+pi+zero+ethernet

Comment: If you need Ethernet a PiZero is the wrong device. Why not use serial (or serial over USB) to exchange data with Arduino.

Comment: @M.Rostami Thanks for your reply. I never saw that before, so I might have to consider it.

Comment: @Milliways I'm not using Ethernet to program an Arduino. I need Ethernet for the Pi Zero to communicate with other computers, and I need the Pi Zero due to space restrictions and being in a dead spot with no WiFi. Previously, when I connected a Pi 2 to an Arduino Uno, in an isolated space, there were issues with loose USB connections, so I'm also looking for other alternatives to program/communicate with an Arduino without the use of USB. Someone else mentioned UART, but I never tried that before.

Comment: Pleasure. There is plenty of modules or hats for RPi Zero without wireless. But the problem with them is their prices. You can buy a RPi Zero for 5$ but if you wanna add a module like that, you need to pay approximately 15$ that is not affordable.

Comment: @M.Rostami I found it on Waveshare's website for $10, and I have to go that route due to circumstances. I found some other Ethernet hats, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on them, and the one kickstarter board looked like it disappeared, so this may be my only option.